# SQL: What is the best way to insert and query a list of organized data?

Tags: sql, list, sorting

This is a rather simple use case that I think there has **got** to be a "standard" solution for, but I can't find any examples.

I am fairly new to SQL (just started learning), so maybe it is blindingly obvious.

Say I have three arrays  of data:

```
seconds: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 6]
height:  [0, 10, 20, 25, 20, 10, 0]
speed:   [10,10,  5,  0, -5,-10, 0]
```

I am going to be getting a whole bunch more height and speed arrays, but they all have the same second/timestamp.

Questions:

- what is the best way to create a table/tables to store this data?

  - My current understanding is that I have to create a table who's **columns** are named "0", "1", "2", "3", etc -- is this correct???
- what is the best way to actually store this data using SQL commands?
- what is the best way to retrieve this data so that everything is in the same order I put it as?

Again, I think this question should be so easy it's stupid, but if something like this is NOT easy to do in SQL, I'm wondering if it is the data base I should be using.

Thanks

**Thanks to binderbound for the answer**

I was thinking of things from the viewpoint of something like Excel, where you would not want to ever store data downwards in column format. But it makes so much sense now because you have the power of sql to generate your queries to however you want them to be. You can put your data like his answer suggests and it is easy to query it how you want it.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Does the array size differ? What I mean is: Does the seconds array sometimes contain 7 values and sometimes 25? Or is is always 7?

Comment: For this we can assume it is always 7. I know if I wanted it to sometimes be 1000, I would need to have 1000 columns (based on my limited understanding). I would then need to populate the rest with null or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create table's with columns 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. I would not recommend having six columns though. It's just bad schema design, even though it may work in your situation.
Rather than store a whole trial in a row, each row should really only store an individual second. That way, adding more seconds in future is a fairly simple process

Following this principle, here is  a rough schema

```
HeightSpeedEntry
_______________
TrialId   PK  int
Seconds   PK  int
Height    PK  int
Speed     PK  int
```

To create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE HeightSpeedEntry(
TrialId int,
Seconds int,
Height int,
Speed int,
CONSTRAINT pk_trial_seconds PRIMARY KEY (TrialId, Seconds));
```

To insert data row by row

```
INSERT INTO HeightSpeedEntry(TrialId, Seconds, Height, Speed)
VALUES (1, 0, 0, 10)

INSERT INTO HeightSpeedEntry(TrialId, Seconds, Height, Speed)
VALUES (1, 1, 10, 10)
```

To retrieve a set of records

```
SELECT * FROM HeightSpeedEntry
WHERE TrialId = 1
ORDER BY Seconds
```

How to actually pass the array into the insert statement in a non-manual fashion depends on where your array is coming from.

Just to re-clarify, what we're doing here is converting your records from this:

```
seconds: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 6]
height:  [0, 10, 20, 25, 20, 10, 0]
speed:   [10,10,  5,  0, -5,-10, 0]
```

to this:

```
HeightSpeedEntry: [1, 0, 0,  10 ]
HeightSpeedEntry: [1, 1, 10, 10 ]
HeightSpeedEntry: [1, 2, 20, 5  ]
HeightSpeedEntry: [1, 3, 25, 0  ]
HeightSpeedEntry: [1, 4, 20, -5 ]
HeightSpeedEntry: [1, 5, 10, -10]
HeightSpeedEntry: [1, 6, 0,  0  ]
```

Comment: Why do you not recommend having six columns? This is an interesting solution that I hadn't considered, and is now making more sense to me. To get my data I just do separate queries like you said. I think I was thinking about this too much like excel or csv, where this format would be very bad.

Comment: What if I wanted to be able to add a variable "acceleration". I've heard that kind of thing is difficult in sql. Is there a database design method in sql that makes this easy? Maybe if I wanted to add three more variables: tempeature, humidity, and wind_speed I would just create a new table for that (with a trial_id and seconds to link it to this table)? Or is it actually easy to do that in sql?

Comment: For a start, you would actually need more than 6 columns. You're columns would be:
height1, speed1, height2, speed2, height3, speed3, height4, speed4, heigh5, speed5, height6, speed6

Comment: oh, for the "solution" I was thinking of -- ya your's is much better :D I hadn't been thinking along the right lines.

Comment: To add more variables, you add more columns using an ALTER TABLE statement. Then you'd have to add the values using an UPDATE statement something like UPDATE HeightSpeedEntry SET Acceleration=x WHERE TrialId=1 AND Second=2. You'd probably want to change your table name too. Alternatively, you can add another table that links, but as it is a 1:1 relationship, there isn't much point

Comment: And that kind of operation is fast (for large amounts of data)? This is more out of curiosity than necessity. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: You're welcome. The operation is not terribly fast, but not that inefficient either. Still - far better to get the columns you want now than to add them in later.

Comment: Ahh, One thought. You could add another table something like TrialId, Second, ValueType, Value. That would allow you to store any number of extra attributes for your trial without adding more columns